# Method returning value before code can run to update the value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the below example, I call a method `signinUser(username, password)` This then runs through Firebase to determine if the user has successfully or unsuccessfully been able to sign in. However, it takes Firebase a short amount of time to do this, which by that time the method has already returned with the original value, before being updated by the successful-ness / unsuccessful-ness of the sign in process.

How would I go about returning the method once the Firebase authentication has done it's thing. I am aware I could put a timer on when the return statement is called, however, I'm not sure how that'd work as slow internet connects could cause it to take longer than the given amount set by a timer.

My code is as follows:

```
public AuthSuccess signinUser(String username, String password) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username + "@debugrestaurant.com", password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            authSuccess = new AuthSuccess(true, null);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Unsuccessful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            authSuccess = new AuthSuccess(false, task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception: " + authSuccess.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        return authSuccess;
    }
```

Please note that the class `AuthSuccess` is simply an object I've created to collect whether or not the sign in was successful, and if not, to collect the exception.

Comment: Make the method void and have the onComplete call whatever code you want to run next.

Comment: Great idea! @BakonJarser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return something now that hasn't been loaded yet. With other words, you cannot simply use the `authSuccess` object outside the `onComplete()` method because it will always be `null` due the asynchronous behaviour of this method. This means that by the time you are trying to return that result outside that method, the data hasn't finished loading yet from the database and that's why is not accessible. A quick solve for this problem would be to use the value of `authSuccess` only inside the `onComplete()` method, otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have exaplined how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wasn't sure it could be done, but the clarification confirms it can't. I think the comment by @BakonJarser is actually quite a good way of getting around the issue, however yours are just as good. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the method signature to void will not solve the asynchronous issue. You can solve this only if your waiting for the data.

Comment: I see. I will look further into this issue tomorrow

Comment: Have you tried my solution above? Is there everything alright?

Comment: I've had a look at your post and video which I'm sure are very useful, however I'm having troubles understanding some of it as I am not familiar with certain things you use. However, I have created an alternate solution which likely isn't as good as yours, but it works just fine for now.

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170706/discussion-between-idleapps-inc-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Sorry I thought I did. I've done it now. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your old code is probably something like this

```
public void onSignInClick(){
    AuthSuccess result = signinUser(username, password);
    if(result.success){
        startMainActivity();
    }else{
        showErrorPopUp();
    }
}
```

Change this to:

```
public void onSignInClick(){
    signinUser(username, password);
}
protected void handleLoginResult(AuthSuccess result){
    if(result.success){
        startMainActivity();
    }else{
        showErrorPopUp();
    }
}
```

And at the very end of your `onComplete` method do:

```
handleLoginResult(authSuccess);
```